# Как правильно построить две колонки на Css grid

Tags: html, css, html5, css-grid

> Не получается построить две колонки [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.main{
 display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 500px 800px;
 grid-gap: 10px; 
}
```

```html
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Main</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static './css/main.css' %}">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static './css/reset.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="main">
  <div class="header">
   <h1 class='user-title'>Musik</h1>
   <img src="{% static './img/User.png' %}" width="300" height="300" alt="user-title" class="user-picture">
   <nav class="header-menu">
    <ul class="header-list">
     <li class="header-item">
      <a href="#!" class="header-link">My Posts</a>
     </li>
     <li class="header-item">
      <a href="#!" class="header-link">Posts</a>
     </li>
     <li class="header-item">
      <a href="#!" class="header-link">Friends</a>
     </li>
     <li class="header-item">
      <a href="#!" class="header-link">Edit</a>
     </li>
     <li class="header-item">
      <a href="#!" class="header-link">Exit</a>
     </li>

    </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="posts">
   <img src="{% static './img/User.png' %}" width="100" height="100" alt="user-title" class="user-picture">
   <h2 class="post-title">Moving To A New Location</h2>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: у вас в примере все работает, уверены что в оригинале у вас стили подключаются?

Comment: Может ему просто ширины экрана не хватает? открыта панель разработчика и вторая колонка просто переносится? Как видно в тултипе у курсора длина блока 1034 px, а заявлено на 1300. В этом случае можно прописать частями, а не пикселями `grid-template-columns: 500px auto` или так `grid-template-columns: 5fr 8fr`

Comment: @Maksim Tikhonov закрыл панель,заработало)0))0спасибо